# Trouble with Date.Now.ToFileTime.ToString command (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, automation, file-writing

I am trying to use the `Date.Now.ToFileTime.ToString` command in Visual Studio to assign the date and time to a text file name along with a suffix, however I am getting results such as the following:

> 131032106994631586log_detailed

Ideally what I would like to see is a file name of this type:

> 20160323_112154_log_detailed.txt

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub writeLog()

    Using outfile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Date.Now.ToFileTime.ToString + "log_detailled.txt", True)
        outfile.Write(sb_detailled.ToString())
    End Using

    Using outfile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Date.Now.ToFileTime.ToString + "log_Ends.txt", True)
        outfile.Write(sb_ends.ToString())
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: `mydt.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") & "_log_detailed.txt"`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make it work with the code you submited, it would be:

```
Private Sub writeLog()

    Using outfile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}_log_detailed.txt", Now), True)
        outfile.Write(sb_detailled.ToString())
    End Using

    Using outfile As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}_log_Ends.txt", Now), True)
        outfile.Write(sb_ends.ToString())
    End Using

End Sub
```

...although maybe you would like to take a look into the library **log4net**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/ . I think it is highly likely that this library already does what you are trying to do (logging things).

It is largely used, although it is not that easy to have it up and running. This is a nice and detailed "how to": http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/899992/Logging-with-Microsoft-NET

Answer (score 0):

Don't us to filetime!

Use Dateformating in the toString() Function

```
Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + "log_detailled.txt"
```

yyyy for the year, e.g. 2016
MM for the month, e.g. 03 (Capital Letter M is month, small letter is minutes!!)
dd for the day
hh for the hour
mm for the minutes
ss for the seconds

between the elements you can use "_","-" or another char as a seperator!